# NavigationLink are not working but seems ok

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I don't see any failures on my navigation link to another view on my SwiftUI app that I am developing on Xcode.

The colour of the text changes to gray but it does not work. In case I am in other view and I come to that view it works and I don't understand why.

```
NavigationLink(destination: UsernameView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)) {
    Text(" crea una cuenta")
    .font(.normalTitle)
}
```

And on this other one it works but I receive a warning from the program with an error that I should change. Can you help me to adapt to iOS 16?

```
.background(
    NavigationLink(destination: ConfirmationView().navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true), 
        isActive: $shouldNavigateToConfirmation) {
            EmptyView()
        }
)
```

The error on this second code is:

```
'init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or NavigationSplitView
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Are your NavigationLinks embedded in a NavigationView, NavigationStack, or NavigationSplitView?

Comment: @Confuseious I embedded it in a NavigationView and now it works fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`NavigationLink(destination:)` has issues best upgrade to [`NavigationLink(value:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(_:value:)-91u0d) and [`navigationDestination`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/navigationdestination(for:destination:)).